# html: "char overflow" on maxlength attribute with double bytes asian inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Say I have an input field:

```
<input id="myinput" type="text" maxlength="10"/>
```

but suppose that it is meant for double bytes characters. What happens is that, with a standard Japanese input system for example, I can actually "write" in that field without limitations. It seems sometimes the text gets trimmed after hitting enter (for example to convert kana to kanji) but not always and I haven't figured out yet the rule when this happens.

Trimmed or not, this could give quite annoying results (see screen shot) for example since in this particular case I want that input text be displayed in real time in a div below.

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/10bf2kz7/) showing the issue. Of course you need to be able to input in Japanese or Chinese to see the problem.

Is there a way to overcome this in HTML directly? Do I have to go through Javascript/Jquery? In such case some help would be appreciated. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Can you please add in a working example on jsfiddle or codepen to replicate the issue your having for us to check out?

Comment: @NasirT That would take some time and I'm about to go to sleep. Will try to update it tomorrow, thanks for your comment.

Comment: @NasirT I added a fiddle as you asked. Of course you need to be able to use Japanese or Chinese input to see the problem.